# Django-Entangled multiple data in JsonField

Tags: django

Working with django JsonField. Using [django-entangled](https://github.com/jrief/django-entangled) in form. I need data format like below. Need suggestion to avail this.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Test 1",
    "roll": 1,
    "section": "A"
  },
  {
    "name": "Test 2",
    "roll": 2,
    "section": "A"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

With django-entangled this is not possible, because that library does not offer multiple forms of the same kind.

You can however try my next form library [django-formset](https://github.com/jrief/django-formset), which can handle multiple forms of the same kind.